# Using hex values for MIPS j and beq instructions

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to be able to jump 6 instructions ahead for a `beq` instruction. Unfortunately QtSpim is giving me a syntax error when I do:

```
beq $a0, $zero, 0x000018
```

It also doesn't like it when I use a hex address for `j`. I tried using a register that stored the correct address, and that also failed.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: spim only supports labels, but using a register should have worked.

Comment: I've always seen `beq` used with labels.  Have you tried labels?

Comment: It won't allow me to use a register, and my assignment restriction is no labels (really genius). It's just throwing a syntax error. Actually a register works for j, but not beq.

Comment: You're not allowed to use labels at all or you're not supposed to use labels for that statement?  If you can use labels, you can combine the two (and form a `beqr` of sorts).  `jalr` and `jr` work with registers.

Comment: You can avoid `beq` with computed `jr` or a jump table.

Comment: Good point @Jester.  That would work.

Comment: You might think to use the `.word` value of the whole branch instruction, but MARS, at least, won't let you put hex constants via `.word` in the code (`.text`) either..

Comment: you can also produce any instruction yourself with `.byte` writing the whole opcode yourself. If the constraint of no-labels in the task was intended to teach you about how target jump address is calculated, then calculating whole opcode seems ok to me. If the constraint was meant to force you into non-loop/non-jump solution, then encoding `beq` yourself is still fail. (EDIT: oh, Erik actually posted it before me, I'm just blind)